# JQuery- function activated once time

Tags: jquery

I write in JQuery function, which select or unselect all checkbox on page. I have group checkbox.

```
  <input type="checkbox" title="111" value='111' name="cid[]" id='cb1'/>
  ...
  <input type="checkbox" title="nnn" value='nnn' name="cid[]" id='cbn'/>
```

And I have main check box.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckAll" title="Choose all" value="" name="checkall-toggle"/>
```

When I click on this checkbox, all another checkbox must be selected. I use this function:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id=='CheckAll')
    {
        if (this.checked==true)
        {

            $('INPUT[type=\'checkbox\']').attr('checked', true);

        }else
        {
            $('INPUT[type=\'checkbox\']').attr('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

I use Firefox 22.0 ...
When I click 'CheckAll' checkbox, this function selected all checkbox. After this, I click second time on 'CheckAll' checkbox. As result- all checkbox are unselected. But. When I tried in second time select all check box, this is not happend. Why?

Comment: it is working fine.see here http://jsfiddle.net/mJpDJ/

Comment: FWIW: `$(this).attr('id')` is just a long way to write `this.id`, and `if (this.checked==true)` is basically just a long way to write `if (this.checked)`.

Comment: Very strange. But your example not work on my browser too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$(":checkbox").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == 'CheckAll') {
        if (this.checked == true) {
            $('INPUT[type=\'checkbox\']').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $('INPUT[type=\'checkbox\']').prop('checked', false);
        }
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P6bNT/)

Answer (score 0):

[from the docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

As of jQuery 1.6, the **.attr()** method returns undefined for attributes that have 
not been set.To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, 
selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the **.prop()** method.